# Checkout page not found when order created through Drupal Commerce API for not authenticated (anonymous) user

Tags: 7, webforms, commerce, rules

I have the following code inside rules - action (being triggered by webform submission)

```
<?php
global $user;
$product_id = 1;

// Create the new order in checkout; you might also check first to
// see if your user already has an order to use instead of a new one.
$order = commerce_order_new($user->uid , 'checkout_checkout');

// Save the order to get its ID.
commerce_order_save($order);

// Load whatever product represents the item the customer will be
// paying for and create a line item for it.
$product = commerce_product_load($product_id);
$line_item = commerce_product_line_item_new($product, 1, $order->order_id);

// Save the line item to get its ID.
commerce_line_item_save($line_item);

// Add the line item to the order using fago's rockin' wrapper.
$order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
$order_wrapper->commerce_line_items[] = $line_item;

// Save the order again to update its line item reference field.
commerce_order_save($order);

// Redirect to the order's checkout form. Obviously, if this were a
// form submit handler, you'd just set $form_state['redirect'].
drupal_goto('checkout/' . $order->order_id);
?>
```

the code works perfectly when i am logedin, however when i submit the webform as not authenticated user, i get sent to checkout/12, I get page not found.

there is no errors in the log, and i see in the backend that the order was created... please help...

Comment: I don't use cart module, i am following this example http://commerceguys.com/blog/creating-orders-drupal-commerce-api.

12 is just example its the order id, every time i submit it increments, the url is being generated by the commerce if you don't have a cart module activated...

Comment: Looking at the code for `commerce_checkout_menu()`, it looks like the only reason you'd get a 404 is if an order with the provided id doesn't exist. Have you confirmed the order is definitely being created successfully before the redirect happens?

Comment: when i go to the admin/commerce/orders it is there...

Comment: Does the anonymous user role have the `access checkout` permission?

Comment: yes, when the permission is off i get "access denied" instead of page not found

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add the order to the session, see [commerce_checkout_access()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!checkout!commerce_checkout.module/function/commerce_checkout_access/7).

Something like this should work:

```
$_SESSION['commerce_cart_orders'][] = $order->order_id;
```

between saving the order and redirecting.